# Gradle Kotlin: Could not find net.sf.saxon:saxon-HE:9.9.0-2

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, saxon, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Saxon doesn't seem to be where `gradle` is trying to send it:

```
Not Found

For request 'GET /artifact/net/sf/saxon/saxon-HE/9.9.0-2/saxon-HE-9.9.0-2.pom'
```

The actual `URL` is, or [looks](http://%20https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE) to be, `../artifact/net.sf.saxon/..` rather than `..artifact/net/saxon..` which causes a problem.

How do I tell the `kotlin-gradle-dsl`, specifically, which repo to look in and how to look in that repo?

kotlin build file:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE
compile group: 'net.sf.saxon', name: 'Saxon-HE', version: '9.9.0-2'



/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    java

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building an application
    application
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()


   maven {
        setUrl("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/")
    }  
   maven {
        setUrl("http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/")
    }  
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is found on compile classpath of this component and consumers.
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre")


    compile (group = "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup"  , name = "tagsoup"     , version = "1.2.1")
    compile (group = "net.sf.saxon"            , name = "saxon-HE"   , version = "9.9.0-2")


    // Use TestNG framework, also requires calling test.useTestNG() below
    testImplementation("org.testng:testng:6.14.3")
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application
    mainClassName = "helloWorldSaxon.App"
}

val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
    // Use TestNG for unit tests
    useTestNG()
}




Executing: gradle clean build
Arguments: [-c, /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldSaxon/settings.gradle.kts]

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find net.sf.saxon:saxon-HE:9.9.0-2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/saxon/saxon-HE/9.9.0-2/saxon-HE-9.9.0-2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/saxon/saxon-HE/9.9.0-2/saxon-HE-9.9.0-2.jar
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/saxon/saxon-HE/9.9.0-2/saxon-HE-9.9.0-2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/saxon/saxon-HE/9.9.0-2/saxon-HE-9.9.0-2.jar
       - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net/sf/saxon/saxon-HE/9.9.0-2/saxon-HE-9.9.0-2.pom
       - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net/sf/saxon/saxon-HE/9.9.0-2/saxon-HE-9.9.0-2.jar
       - http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/net/sf/saxon/saxon-HE/9.9.0-2/saxon-HE-9.9.0-2.pom
       - http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/net/sf/saxon/saxon-HE/9.9.0-2/saxon-HE-9.9.0-2.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date



Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle clean build
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type in the name artifact, instead of

```
compile (group = "net.sf.saxon"            , name = "saxon-HE"   , version = "9.9.0-2")
```

It should be

```
compile (group = "net.sf.saxon"            , name = "Saxon-HE"    , version = "9.9.0-2")
```

Comment: you mean capitalize "Saxon"?  I tried that, similar result.  I honestly didn't know that the name mattered, thought that was just a local alias.  But I'm looking at that `net.sf.saxon` in the `group` artifact.  But, `tagsoup` uses a similar naming convention and it works fine.